# The GET term dose not get received by ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is my jquery:

```
$("#sq").autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxautocomplete.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 6,
        name_startsWith: request.term
        },
            success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                label: item ,
                value: item
                }
            }));
            }
    });
    },
    minLength: 1,
});
```

and my php:

```
echo json_encode(array($_GET['term']));
```

The problem is that the php dose not receive the term. why?

Comment: You haven't sent `term` in your data. Maybe you want `name_startsWith`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the any parameter `term`. You are passing this data:

```
   data: {
    featureClass: "P",
    style: "full",
    maxRows: 6,
    name_startsWith: request.term
   },
```

so you can get this by:

```
echo $_REQUEST['featureClass'];
echo $_REQUEST['style'];
echo $_REQUEST['maxRows'];
echo $_REQUEST['name_startsWith'];
```

You don't have any `term` parameter I think you are talking about the `name_startsWith`.

For that use this:

```
echo json_encode($_REQUEST['name_startsWith']);
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
     echo json_encode(array($_GET['name_startsWith']));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access like `$_GET['term']` there should be a `name-value-pair` like `term=something` in the `AJAX` request. which is not there.

Answer (score -1):

Try some thing like this by adding type:GET

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajaxautocomplete.php",
        type:GET,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 6,
        name_startsWith: request.term
```